# winsock - An invalid argument was supplied (on bind)

Tags: sockets, udp, window, winsock, winsock2

This problem is driving me nuts.

I create a socket and set SO_REUSEADDR.

```
thisSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
int i = 1;
setsockopt(thisSocket , SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&i, (int)sizeof(i));
```

When I bind:

```
sockaddr_in_t sock_addr;
memset(&sock_addr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in_t));

sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sock_addr.sin_port   = htons(_listeningPort);
sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");

bind(thisSocket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_t*>(&sock_addr), sizeof(sock_addr));
```

I sometimes get an error:

```
 "An invalid argument was supplied"
```

What am I doing wrong here? And why am I getting this error?

**UPDATE**

Turns out that packets were being sent on the socket before bind() was called. This caused bind() to return an error.

Comment: The code you showed is fine, so it has to be a problem in code you haven't shown. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the error in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that packets were being sent on the socket before bind() was called. This caused bind() to return an error.

Comment: Yup, this is the answer. I was, too, sending before bind, which caused the bind to fart. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per the [`bind()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550.aspx) documentation:

> WSAEINVAL
>
> An invalid argument was supplied.
>
> **This error is returned of the socket `s` is already bound to an address.**

The error means that `thisSocket` has already had a successful `bind()` called on it, and you are trying to `bind()` it again.

Comment: Yes that is what the documentation says, but that's not what I'm seeing. The variable thisSocket is part of a C++ class and a new instance of that class is created....so how can a successful bind already have been called on that socket?

Comment: @user1884325 nobody can answer that since you didn't show that code yet. Please edit your question to show your class and how it is being used. It is obviously doing something differently than you are expecting.